# Why does this recursive function pass an empty collection to `take`?

Tags: clojure, scheme, lisp

I'm trying to write an implementation of Clojure's `partition-all` function in Scheme:

```scm
(define (take lst n)
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons (car lst) (take (cdr lst) (- n 1)))))

(define (partition-all n step coll)
  (if (not (null? coll))
      (cons (take coll (min n (length coll)))
            (partition-all n step (list-tail coll step)))))
```

But the interpreter yells at me:

```
cdr: expected pair in argument #1
```

This means that, at some point, an empty list `'()` is being passed to `take` which should never happen due to the conditional `(not (null? coll))` in the `partition-all` function.

What's wrong with my function?

Comment: In partition-all, your `if` has no 'else' case. Could you edit your program to indicate which Scheme you're trying this with, and what arguments you're providing to `partition-all` to cause this error?

Comment: What is `list-tail` doing? Are you **absolutely sure** that the error comes from the `take` function, and not from `list-tail` (or a recursive call of itself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following what I said in my comment, I'm very sure that it's **not** the `cdr` in `take` that is giving you issues. Running your code in guile on ideone gives me:

> ERROR: In procedure list-tail:
>
> ERROR: In procedure list-tail: Wrong type argument in position 1 (expecting pair): ()

Thus, the issue is that you're trying to get a tail of a list that's not long enough. This can be mitigated by only taking the minimum of `step` and the collections length:

```scm
(define (take lst n)
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons (car lst) (take (cdr lst) (- n 1)))))

(define (partition-all n step coll)
  (if (not (null? coll))
      (cons (take coll (min n (length coll)))
            (partition-all n step (list-tail coll (min (length coll) step))))
                                                 ;;^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      '()
    ;;^^^
         ))


(display (partition-all 3 2 '(a b c d e f g)))
; => ((a b c) (c d e) (e f g) (g))
```

([Live on ideone](http://ideone.com/swXU27))

Note that I added also an else case to the `if`, otherwise the result list is ended not with `'()` (the empty list), but with an unspecified value.

Also note that neither of your functions is tail-recursive.